# Splitting an arraylist and merging them back again

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, user-defined-types

I have made a class named OutlierInfo as follows

```
public class OutlierInfo 
{
    public String month;
    public int year;
    public String id;
    public int serialId;

    public void setSerialId(int serialid)
    {   
        serialId=serialid;   
    }

    public void setMonth(String monthh)
    {   
        month=monthh; 
    }

    public void setYear(int yearr)
    {    
        year=yearr;  
    }

    public void setId(String idd)
    {        
        id=idd;   
    }   
}
```

Ad I have an arraylist of  type Outlierinfo.I have added some objects of OutlierInfo to the arraylist. Now what  I have to do is  group the objects according to their SerialId, make arraylist of each of the groups then merge all the arraylists of the groups
This is the code that I have written but it just throws error and  I have no idea why.I need some help in finding out why the following code gives error?

```
public class ArraylistSort 
{
    ArrayList<OutlierInfo> result = new ArrayList();
    static ArrayList<ArrayList<OutlierInfo>> groupResult = new ArrayList<ArrayList<OutlierInfo>>();
    String[] months = { "JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR"  ,
                        "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG"  ,
                        "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DECM"
                      };
    int counter=0;
    int count=0;   

    public ArraylistSort(){

        for(int i=0;i<2;i++)   
        {
            for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
            {     
                int year=2000+j;
                OutlierInfo o=setValues(i,months[j],year);
                result.add(o);
                System.out.println("result size"+result.size());
            }
        }

        while(result.size()!=0)
        {      
            OutlierInfo info1=new OutlierInfo();
            info1=result.get(counter);
            ArrayList<OutlierInfo> partialInfo=new ArrayList();

            for(int j=1;j<count;j++)
            {      
                OutlierInfo info2=new OutlierInfo();
                info2=result.get(j);
                if(info1.serialId==info2.serialId)
                {   
                    partialInfo.add(info2);
                    result.remove(info2);
                }                                                  
            }

            partialInfo.add(info1);
            System.out.println("partiainfosize"+partialInfo.size());
            groupResult.add(partialInfo);
            result.remove(info1);
            System.out.println("r size "+result.size());
        }

        count=result.size();
    }

    private OutlierInfo setValues(int id,String month,int year)
    {
        OutlierInfo a = new OutlierInfo(); 
        a.setSerialId(id);
        a.setMonth(month);
        a.setYear(year);

        return a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArraylistSort as=new ArraylistSort();
    }
}
```

I get the following error :Can someone help me understand the error?do i have any logic errors?

```
initial size 0
result size1
result size2
result size3
result size4
result size5
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 6, Size: 6
result size6
result size7
result size8
    at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
    at STAnalysis.ArraylistSort.<init>(ArraylistSort.java:56)
    at STAnalysis.ArraylistSort.main(ArraylistSort.java:98)
Java Result: 1
```

## UPDATE

The biggest confusion that  am currently facing is that the error "index out of bounds" is thrown when i am actually adding objects to the arraylist!

## UPDATE

i fixed it.Turns out i had messed up with the curleybraces.My final code

```
public class StAnamoliesSequencer 
{
    ArrayList<OutlierInfo> stAnomalies =new ArrayList();//arraylist of spatio-temporal outliers
    ArrayList<ArrayList<OutlierInfo>> sequencedStAnomalies=new ArrayList<ArrayList<OutlierInfo>>();
    int firstElement;

    public StAnamoliesSequencer()
    {
         firstElement=0;      
    }


    public ArrayList<ArrayList<OutlierInfo>> sequenceStAnomalies(ArrayList<OutlierInfo> sTanomalies)
    {      

         int loopSizeDeterminer;//determines teh size of the inner loop and is dynamic.

        for(int index=0;index<sTanomalies.size();index++)
        {  
            OutlierInfo stOutlier=new OutlierInfo();
            stOutlier=sTanomalies.get(index);
            stAnomalies.add(index, stOutlier);
        }

           loopSizeDeterminer=stAnomalies.size();

           while(stAnomalies.size()!=0)
             {      
                   OutlierInfo stOutlier1=new OutlierInfo();
                   ArrayList<OutlierInfo> tracker=new ArrayList();//arraylist that stores the grouped Outliers to be deleted later
                   stOutlier1=stAnomalies.get(firstElement);
                   ArrayList<OutlierInfo> similarOutlier=new ArrayList();//similaroutliers are kept in an arraylist
                   similarOutlier.add(stOutlier1);
                   tracker.add(stOutlier1);

                for(int index=1;index<loopSizeDeterminer;index++)
                {    
                     OutlierInfo stOutlier2=new OutlierInfo();
                     stOutlier2=stAnomalies.get(index);

                               if(stOutlier1.serialId==stOutlier2.serialId)
                               {  
                                   similarOutlier.add(stOutlier2);
                                   tracker.add(stOutlier2);
                               }

                }


                System.out.println("partiainfosize \t"+similarOutlier.size());

                sequencedStAnomalies.add(similarOutlier);//adding arraylist of similar outliers to the arraylist of arraylist

                for(int index=0;index<tracker.size();index++)
                {
                     OutlierInfo groupedOutlier=new OutlierInfo();
                     groupedOutlier=tracker.get(index);
                     stAnomalies.remove(groupedOutlier);//grouped outliers are removed from original arraylist containing spatio-temporal outliers to reduce redundancy
                }

                System.out.println(" size "+stAnomalies.size());
                loopSizeDeterminer=stAnomalies.size();




    }
        return sequencedStAnomalies;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please read carefully:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 6, Size: 6`

Arrays index in java and most of modern programming languages since 1970 :) start from 0. If your array is 6 elements long its index must be in range of 0 ... 5.

I hope that now you have enough information to debug your code and find the bug.

Comment: I know that.I am basically adding objects dynamically to this arraylist and accordingly the size of the arraylist is increasing and because i have added 8 objects here to this arralist its size have to be 8 so why that exception when  the program is trying to access the 6th object?Cool i didnot know that such indexing started from 1970:)

Answer (score 1):

hey I ran your code and checked it.
Here is the output

```
result size1
result size2
result size3
result size4
result size5
result size6
result size7
result size8
partiainfosize1
r size 7
partiainfosize1
r size 6
partiainfosize1
r size 5
partiainfosize1
r size 4
partiainfosize1
r size 3
partiainfosize1
r size 2
partiainfosize1
r size 1
partiainfosize1
r size 0
```

Check in some other IDE, if your using eclipse(try in Netbeans) and check if you still have errors

Answer (score 0):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 6, Size: 6
```

says that you have an arraylist of size 6 and you are trying to access an element at 6th index. **which is wrong**

remember that arraylist indexes are zero indexed. so, if your arraylist is of size 6, to access the 6th element you should do

```
al.get(5).
```

my guess is, your count is 6, thus your loop should be

```
 for(int j=0;j<count-1;j++)
                {      
                     OutlierInfo info2=new OutlierInfo();
                     info2=result.get(j);

         /// continue your code
```

Comment: Thank you:) but my problem here is hardly that(atleast i think so)or may be i have misunderstood dont know.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an index out of bounds exception which is almost always a programmers error. However I took your exact posted code and it worked fine no exceptions. I realizes your error says error in ArrayListSort.java:98 so line 98 the class you posted has only 59 lines! So you are running the wrong version of your own class make sure you are running the one you posted. That was the problem.

My results from running YOUR POSTED code unmodified

result size1
result size2
result size3
result size4
result size5
result size6
result size7
result size8
partiainfosize1
r size 7
partiainfosize1
r size 6
partiainfosize1
r size 5
partiainfosize1
r size 4
partiainfosize1
r size 3
partiainfosize1
r size 2
partiainfosize1
r size 1
partiainfosize1
r size 0

Comment: Hey i deleted some comments while posting for clarity:) and also i deleted some lines that basically printed stuff. i see no logical error but i just keep getting that ^array out of bounds error^thank you for running the code and posting the result.I have no idea why i keep getting that error